# How can i make a conditional WHERE clause (or alternate way)

Tags: mysql, sql

I try to count all the rows that are in an "invalid" state. This can be different statuses, field content, and, here is my problem, when a status that would be okay and two fields are not the same, it still would count as invalid

```
SELECT count(status) 
    FROM db.table 
    WHERE name LIKE  '".$needle."' AND 
    (
        (
            (                           
            status LIKE 'NOT%OK' OR         /* listing all status that we want to catch     */
            status LIKE 'XY' OR
            status LIKE 'XYZ' OR 
            unauth_change IS NOT NULL       /* also those where unauth_change is not empty  */
            ) OR 
            (
            status LIKE 'OK' AND            /* if the status is "ok" though and the     */
            planned_place = actual_place    /* planned and actual place on are not same     */
            )                               /* then still count it                          */
        )
        AND
        override NOT LIKE 'Y'               /* overridden items are discarded anyway        */      
    )  LIMIT 1;
```

I tried IF functions but failed and i am not even sure it will work the way i intended. Below query is the latest test where i want to say "(either 'status' is invalid" OR "status is valid but planned and actual are not the same") AND "rest of clauses".
i tried also IF(status ='ok',planned_place = actual_place,1) but i was, honestly speaking, fishing in the dark.

sample rows and expected result

```
name| status |  unauth_change | planned_place | actual_place | override | COUNT?|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
abc | notok  |                | A             | A            | N        | yes
cde | xy     |                | A             | A            | N        | yes
efg | xyz    |                | A             | A            | Y        | no (override)
hij | ok     | blablabla      | A             | A            | N        | yes (unauth)
lmn | ok     |                | A             | B            | N        | yes (planned/actual)
opq | ok     |                | A             | A            | N        | no
```

List item

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(name)
FROM tableNameHere
WHERE name LIKE searchTermHere
AND (status NOT LIKE 'ok'
OR unauth_change IS NOT NULL
OR planned_place != actual_place)
AND override LIKE 'N'
```